# Node.js on windows tries to run linux version of newman

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, postman, newman

I have newman (shell runner for postman tests) installed on Windows 10.
When i try to run a script via node which calls the newman module i get the following error:

```
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:599:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous>
```

It is trying to run some bash code here which fails for obvious reasons. 
I noticed that in the C:...\AppData\Roaming\npm folder there are two files for newman - a windows batch script and a linux bash script both called newman which contains the code mentioned above.

Why is it trying to run the linux version of newman on my windows machine? When i remove the bash script it says it cannot find a newman module. It doesn't even try to run the windows batch file instead, it is completely ignored.

Edit: Just reinstalled npm newman module just to be sure, didn't help.

Comment: Can you not do an uninstall of Newman `npm uninstall -g newman` so it's completely removed and then install it again. Sounds obvious but i had to ask or is this a local project dependency and you're not using it on the command line?

Comment: @DannyDainton I already did a global reinstall, unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: It baffles me how appearantly no one has ever dealt with that problem before. You really can't find anything about it anywhere.

Comment: Do you use Bash on Ubuntu for Win 10? Is there some sort of USERPROFILE weirdness going on there?

Comment: @DannyDainton I have Git Bash installed with the Git package for windows but thats about it. Looking at my local and system environment settings i cannot seem to find anything suspicious.